# What could one spray inside solid core door to protect wood and create a tunnel?

Tags: doors, plastic, finish, pet-door

What could one spray inside solid core door to protect wood and create a tunnel?
Bought a pet door for a solid core door. Installed it, looks great, ezcept turns out the company doesn't make a tunnel for the door.

Is there any thing or combination of things I could spray that would cure to a plastic feel with a white-ish color?

If not, the door was cheap. I could always exchange it.

Is plasti-dip an option?

[image: greatest piece of craftsmanship known to man]

Comment: I would probably make some boards that fit inside the opening and screw or staple them in place. Spray foam could help put two much will make a mess.

Comment: Retrofit window guys have strips of thin-ish (like, 1/16") pvc that could coat the inside of the door. They come in various widths, but I'm sure you could get close to 1-3/4". If you were describing it to the window guy, you'd call it the filler strip that sticks to the face of the window and bridges the gap to the jamb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try iron-on white melamine banding, usually used to finish the edges of particle board for cabinets or furniture. The banding usually comes in ¾" or ⅝" wide sizes, and it may be a challenge to find the banding in the width you need, but I know I've seen it in a few places.

Comment: Presumable there would be no need to iron it on, since a piece of the right length would just jam into place. Might need a blow-dryer to warm up the strip enough to bend that sharply though.

Answer (score 4):

I think if you use a couple coats of good primer and a finish coat of enamel paint, you should be fine. Just be sure to work it into the wood well. Two thin coats are always better than one thick coat.  The cat door is gonna protect the cut edges quite a bit as well. Put a small bead of silicone caulk on the inside of the cat door bezel before you install it on the outside surface to seal that possible entry point from rain water.

Answer (score 2):

You bought a pet flap made for a thinner door. There are pet flaps that come made for thicker doors that have an adjustment range that covers the thickness of door that you have. Some indeed will also come with a tunnel piece which gets discarded when installing on a thinner door.

I would recommend returning the pet flap for one designed for the thicker door. Hopefully the opening you cut is compatible with the replacement door.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try white adhesive tape. Duct tape or electrical tape.  If that flakes out after a few weeks or months, then try something stiffer like the Formica idea.